# Meaning of " $N || {}" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did C( and a bit of C++)programming all my life till now and started to learn Javascript recently.

I am having tough time to understand some of the Javascript Syntax.

Can someone explain me the following line :

```
window.$N = $N || {};
```

Thanks!

Comment: if global variable `$N` is defined (or truthy, to be pedentic) leave it as is, if not, declare it as an empty object.

Comment: It's a default value. The expression `$N || {}` means "`$N` if `$N` is 'truthy' otherwise `{}`".

Answer (score 0):

In browsers, the `window` object is global.

If `$N` is falsy, `{}` will be assigned to `window.$N`.  If `$N` is truthy, its value will be assigned to `window.$N` (keeping the same value probably).

This is a common way to override default values.